# How to get the contents of a message in Discord.PY

Tags: discord.py

I have seen multiple websites telling me to use `message.content`, but it seems like that doesn't exist. When I use `print(message)`, content doesn't seem to exist. I also tried besides that with this code.

```
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    print(message.content)
    print(message.author.name)
    print(message.channel.name)
```

[It prints "", "Com" and "test"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKHrP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick look through the docs will tell you that `Message.content` [does exist](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message%20content#discord.Message.content). That same section of the documentation also mentions that you need the `Message Content Intent` to be able to read the contents of messages.

> The actual contents of the message. **If Intents.message_content is not enabled this will always be an empty string unless the bot is mentioned or the message is a direct message.**

For more info on intents, again just read the docs. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! I couldn't find anything like this in the docs.

Comment: If you search for ``message.content`` it's literally the first result...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to enable the message content intent in your code and in the discord developer portal why?, message content intent is a privileged intent.
See the docs:

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html

How to enable this intent in the developer portal?:

Log in to discord, go to the developer portal, select your application, hit the menu button and go to the "Bot" section, you'll see a toggle for message content intent, toggle it on.

Now for the code part:

```
import discord
intents = discord.Intents.default()
Intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
#If you're creating a client.

#OR

from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
#If you're developing a bot

#Rest of the code goes here
```